# how to find both the conditions using $or operator in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to get emailaddress or phoneNumber matching records.I used the below query to get the result.

```
user.find({ $or:[{emailAddress: "testemail@gmail.com" , phoneNumber: "123456789"}]})
```

But when i use the query result is showing 0 records.

What i want is :

```
{
    "phoneNumber" : "123456789",
    "emailAddress" : "testemail@gmail.com"
},
{
    "phoneNumber" : "8008465488",
    "emailAddress" : "testemail@gmail.com"
}
```

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting is off; if we add some indenting, we can see that the $or is being given a list with one item in, and that item has two properties:

```
$or: [
     {
            emailAddress: "testemail@gmail.com" ,
            phoneNumber: "123456789"
    }
]
```

What you want is a list of two possibilities, each with one property:

```
$or: [
     {
            emailAddress: "testemail@gmail.com"
     },
     {
            phoneNumber: "123456789"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Query with a slight modification in it will do the trick

```
user.find({ $or:[{emailAddress: "testemail@gmail.com"} , {phoneNumber: "123456789"}]})
```

Syntax for [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) - `{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }`